# XOR of N elements after M timestamps of modification in them

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor

> There are N elements (numbered 1 to N). All are Zero initially.  There
> are M timestamps. In each timestamp, all the elements numbered between
> L and R (both inclusive) increased by P.  Find XOR of all elements
> after M timestamps.

## Input Format

> The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the
> number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows. The
> first line contains two space-separated integers N, M. M lines follow.
> The ith of these M lines contains three space-separated integers L, R,
> P, describing the ith timestamp.

### Constraints

> 1 < T < 100
> 1 < N < 1e16
> 0 < M < 1e4
> 1 < L < R < N
> 0 < P < 1e9
> Sum of M over all test cases do not exceed 1e5

### My approach

```
while(t--){
          long long n,m;
          cin>>n>>m;
          long long a[n+1]={0};
          while(m--){
              ll x,y,p;
              cin>>x>>y>>p;
             for(int i=x;i<=y;i++)
              a[i]=a[i]+p;
          }
          long long  ans=0;
          for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
          ans=ans^a[i];
 
          cout<<ans<<"\n";
      }
```

I can only come up with a bruteforce idea by which it seems impossible to solve because the constraints are too large.

How can I answer each test case in O(1) time. Thet Time limit for this question is only 1 sec.

Comment: Do you have an example input file and expected outputs?

Comment: `O(1)` time (per test case) is impossible. Obviously you have to (at least) *read* the `M` timestamps which takes `O(M)` time. But note that `M≪N`. Your algorithm is in `O(M·N)` time. [Dannyadam's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63370142/6770384) is in `O(M·log M)` time (`log M` is only there because the lookup table has to be sorted at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `N` elements can be viewed as members of an array.

If there are an even number of contiguous elements with the same value, the XOR of all these elements is zero.

If there are an odd number of contiguous elements with the same value `X`, the XOR of all these elements is `X`.

A solution to this problem is to iterate over the array, keeping track of how many repeated values of `X` there are prior to a change in value, and XOR'ing `X` to the running result if there were an odd number of repeats.

This can be computed without having to actually construct the array, nor loop over each element, by considering only the specified `L` and `R` indices from the input, which indicate the places where an array value may differ from its adjacent neighbor.

Here's an implementation in Python, which reads the input from `stdin`.

```py
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def getline():
    return sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()

T = int(getline())
for _ in range(T):
    N, M = map(int, getline().split())
    lookup = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(M):
        L, R, P = map(int, getline().split())
        lookup[L] += P
        lookup[R + 1] -= P
    lookup[N + 1] = 0
    result = 0
    X = 0
    last_idx = 1
    for idx in sorted(lookup):
        count = idx - last_idx
        if count & 1:
            result ^= X
        X += lookup[idx]
        last_idx = idx
    print(result)
```